# pytest on AWS CodeBuild givers Error : E NameError: name 'add_numbers' is not defined

Tags: python, unit-testing, amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I am using AWS CodeBuild to execute unit test on my python code. When i execute project in CodeBuild , it completes successfully but unit tests are not executed properly. It gives Error  **E NameError: name  add_numbers' is not defined**

add_numbers is a module in my code.py file that just adds 2 numbers.

Note: This unit case runs successfully locally.

here is my code.py:

```
"""Test code to test the pylint & pytest"""
def add_numbers( number_1, number_2):
    """This module add 2 numbers that are given as input"""
    return number_1+number_2
```

here is my unit test

```
"""This is unit test file"""
import code
def test_adding_module():
    """This module tests add_number module"""
    result = code.add_numbers(12, 8)
    assert result == 20
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You either meant `from code import add_numbers` or `result = code.add_numbers(...)`

Comment: Typo error. Edited

Comment: `add_numbers` also shouldn't have a `self` argument.

Comment: Can you please provide Any solutions?

Comment: Remove the `self` argument for `add_numbers`... I can't really be clearer than this.

Comment: That was a typo mistake @pycoder.
btw 'self' was removed before you commented

Answer (score 1):

I solved that problem.
Actually pytest was not able to get Path of Python. Writing following command in Buildspec.yml solved the problem.

```
`export PYTHONPATH=.`
```

That is for Linux , if you are on windows use

`set PYTHONPATH=.`